# Proof of construction of $30^{\circ}, 60^{\circ}, 120^{\circ}$ and $135^{\circ}$ angles

Tags: geometric-construction

What is the proof of constructing $30^{\circ}, 60^{\circ}, 120^{\circ}$ and $135^{\circ}$ angles with ruler and compass? I can prove $90^{\circ}$ by proving that the line joining point of intersection of two circle is perpendicular to the line joining their radius. But I can't prove these angles. Thank You.

Comment: The proof may depend on the actual construction you use.

Comment: The more interesting construction is that of an angle of 36 degrees (or for that matter any multiple of 18 degrees).

Comment: +1 for showing your interest in proofs. Most students learning geometric constructions just try to remember it as a routine procedure.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. If any of them is what you need, you should **accept** it by clicking the grey tick mark below the question score. Otherwise, explain what is still missing in the answers!

Comment: @5xum sorry sir I did not knew that before, i will do that now.

Comment: @RamKeswanim You should do that on all the questions you posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constructing $60^{\circ}$ what we do is, simply construct a equilateral triangle. Since each interior angle of an equilateral triangle is $60^{\circ}$, we're done.

[image]

Here $PA=AB=PB$

Rest is just bisecting this angle to get $30^{\circ}$, and reconstruction of this angle on the side $PA$, to double the angle, thus resulting into $120^{\circ}$

What remains is $135^{\circ}$, for this we construct $90^{\circ}$, again $90^{\circ}$ on previous one, and then bisect later one, getting an angle $90^{\circ}+\frac{90^{\circ}}{2}=135^{\circ}$

Comment: @Jaideej Khare, This consrtuction engages the compass. If I understand OP's question, only the ruler is allowed.

Comment: @szw1710 sorry I forgot to add compass

Comment: sir how do you prove it is an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @RamKeswani Remember that while constructing all the arcs, the length​ of compass remains constant. Thus, when $P$ is the base, $A$ and $B$ are equidistant from$P$ and thus $PA=PB$. In Step 2, we choose $B$ as the base, and keep the length constant, and hence $AB=PA=PB$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare  right sir, I got the proof of it through circles. now how do we prove bisected angles?

Comment: @RamKeswani Bisecting angles is just finding the midpoint of angles, which will lie on the line joining midpoint of chord, and center of circle. Hence, Bisecting angles is basically, Bisecting chords.

Comment: @JaideepKhare i hope you become a mthematician.

Comment: @RamKeswani Thanks, I hope you understand whatever I explained.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Sir why while constructing a perpendicular bisector on a line, the radius should be smaller than the line?

Comment: @RamKeswani: radius need not be smaller than the line segment. In fact it should be greater than half the length of the line segment. But note that choosing a large radius will make your image larger and perhaps some part of it might go outside the page.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes sir I saw that. and also saw that it cannot be less than half the length because then the circles(arc) wint intersect. But what about when it is exactly half the length sir?

Comment: @RamKeswani: at exactly half the length the circles will meet at exactly one point (namely the mid point of the segment). The problem however is that you can't find half the length just by thinking. Drawing a perpendicular bisector is one of the easiest ways to find the mid point and thus half the length of the segment.

Comment: @RamKeswani If the radius is exactly equal to half the length of line segment, then the circles will intersect tangentially at the mid point.

Comment: @JaideepKhare then sir this seems a much easier and faster way. why do schools do not teach us this?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sir we can measure and then divide, or when we are just asked to make any line we can make it a multiple of 2.

Comment: @RamKeswani : I learnt this in school. And measuring involves a marked ruler and this is not allowed in geometric constructions.

Answer (score 0):

See the picture above: if we have $60^{\circ}$, it is easy to draw a right angle. When we have this, $135^{\circ}$ is easy because you can draw a square and its diagonal.